# jQuery append double posting

Tags: jquery, append, double

I have a jquery code that posts to a php page, that is echoing out some results.
When i click on a link and append data, it's doubling the data when you click multi times.
It gives perfectly sense why it does that(i think), but du you have any suggestions on how to prevent the double appending from happening?

Code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.link').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        jQuery.ajax({
          url : "medialib/getpictures.php",
          data: "linkid="+id,
          type : "post",
          success: function(html){
                jQuery('#txtHint').append(html);
        }

        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overwrite data in #txtHint:

```
jQuery('#txtHint').html(html);
```

ps. I hope this is what you are asking

Comment: Gives perfectly sense and is working like a charm - Thanks a lot :)
Don't know why i used append for that^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**,

```
jQuery('#txtHint').html(html);
```

If you want to keep your previous data then try it like,

```
prevHTML=jQuery('#txtHint').html();
newHTML=prevHTML.replace(html,'')+html; // replace previous html if same html comes in
jQuery('#txtHint').html(newHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should disable the link by not allowing the user to click on it and enable when the append is done..

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.link').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        //diable .link click here
        jQuery.ajax({
          url : "medialib/getpictures.php",
          data: "linkid="+id,
          type : "post",
          success: function(html){
                jQuery('#txtHint').append(html);
                //enable it again here
        }

        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Or you can simply replace the existing content using html() function,

Like this,

```
   success: function(html){
       jQuery('#txtHint').html(html);
   }
```